# Laravel get a cookies from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, laravel, cookies, woocommerce, get

I have two site one in wordpress (www.wordpress.it) and one in laravel (www.laravel.it). I set a cookie in wordpress and I want to take it with laravel how can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by 'take it with Laravel'?

Comment: if your wordpress site and laravel site is hosted on same domain and subdomain then you can share the cookies otherwise not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get cookies from other domain for security reasons. What you could do is to create something similar to SID for get request, `?sid=session_id`, and access this way.

You can access sessions only from subdomains.

```
session.cookie_domain = ".domain.com"
```

Comment: Hello frank, thanks for the help.
Could you give me a more explicit example please?

Comment: Hello @palla451 please share some more information about your projects. Are they based on the same domain?

Comment: I have a showcase site in wordpress and when I click on the image of a product redirect to an online booking system. I am developing an online booking system for coworking that has to communicate with the existing Vedrina website and done in wordpress. Through API if the user is registered I have to bring some information back

Comment: But the domain name is the same for both?

Comment: Then I can tell you that the only way in this scenario is to pass sid(session id) in the get uri in wordpress website. wordpress.com?sid=SESSION_ID